# Prove that if the angle between any two of $k$ distinct vectors of Euclidean space $V$ is $\pi/3$ then $k \leq \dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

> Prove that if the angle between any two of $k$ distinct vectors of Euclidean space $V$ is $\pi/3$ then $k \leq \dim V$.

How I've approached this problem so far is to imagine it for $k = 2$ where if we think about the $x_1$ and $x_2$ axis normally separated by $90^\circ$ or $\pi/4$ we now have the two axes a little bit closer (separated by $\pi/3$). However, for $k=2$ we still span the plane.

I'm struggling with finding a rigorous way to actually prove this. (Maybe it would involve projections?) Any help or even just a hint to get started would be appreciated. I find this question very interesting.

Comment: Try to prove that, under the hypothesis, the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: But if I want to show that $k \leq dimV$, wont I eventually be dealing with linear dependent vectors (in the case of strict inequality)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Gerry's idea, we consider vectors $e_1,\dots,e_k$ s.t. for every $i$, $||e_i||^2=1$ and $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=1/2$ when $i\not= j$. Assume that $||\sum_ix_ie_i||^2=0$, that is, $\sum_i{x_i}^2+\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j=0$. The symmetric matrix associated to the previous quadratic form is $A=\dfrac12(I+J)$ where $J$ is the matrix with all entries $1$. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\dfrac12$, $n-1$ times, and $\dfrac{n+1}{2}$. Thus $A$ is $>0$ and the $(x_i)$ are $0$. Finally, the $(e_i)_{i\leq k}$ are linearly independent and $k\leq \dim V$.

Comment: $\sum x_i^2+\sum x_ix_j=0\Rightarrow\sum x_i^2+(\sum x_i)^2=0$

Comment: @   user26857 , yes it is faster.